# Alternative logon for Stack Exchange Chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

As some people (such as me) have problems logging into chat seamlessly, even when passing the [diagnostic test](https://chat.stackexchange.com/help) (login data seems to old). This is especially annoying when I am on another computer and can't remember the link for logging in manually. So, I recommend that:

[image: image mockup]

the button from `http://{your stackexchange site.com}/users/chat-stackexchange-login` is accessible easily from the login page. This would definitely help a sizable number of users, and save a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

The "login data too old" message tells you to fully log out of a SE site and log back in.  Just logging in isn't good because that isn't actually refreshing the global-auth data.  You can do this using the regular log-in and log-out links on any of the sites.  You don't need to remember a special link.

Comment: On multiple occasions I've been logged out of the chat and no amount of logging in and out on SE sites will log me back in. I realize that ideally stuff like that won't happen, but it would be nice to have the ability to log directly into chat as a backup.

Comment: @Rebecca I noticed today that I wasn't being auto-signed-in to chat when I still had a US-based VPN connection active (I'm "normally" in Canada :)). SE sites worked fine, but even after logging out and back in, chat wouldn't sign me in. It worked fine without another logout/login after I disconnected from the VPN. Dunno if this is worth opening a new question for, but I can if needed. I just thought I'd bring this up since it might be related to login issues Kyle's describing too.